# W/Glide: Load failed for [http://myproject.fr/plant.jpg] with dimensions [280x280]

Tags: android, database, firebase, uri, android-glide

I get this error when I run my program
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for plant1 found on class fr.kbrown.myproject.PlantModel
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for plant4 found on class fr.kbrown.myproject.PlantModel
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=17KB, data=31KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=17KB, data=31KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
W/Glide: Load failed for [http://myproject.fr/plant.jpg] with dimensions [280x280]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(, status code: 404)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please also add the content of your `PlantModel` class and the code that reads data from Firebase.